# Has anyone succeedded in streaming rtsp packet using TCP through live 555 libraries

Tags: visual-studio-2010, stream, streaming, rtsp, live555

Has anyone succeedded in **streaming rtsp packet using TCP through live 555 libraries**.?**
I try'ed searching web a lot but didn't find anything useful all the solution provided i try'ed but the **wireshark** shows that **UDP** packet are being streamed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya send the appropriate setup request you will be able to stream over TCP.In case of live 555 subclass "OnDemandServerMediaSession" class.