# Forcing Android to use RTSP/AVP/TCP interleaved

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer, rtsp, rtsp-client

I am using Android 4.1.2 on Galaxy S3. Currently android mediaplayer always tries RTSP UDP (RTP/AVP/UDP) method to connect with RTSP server.

If Android MediaPlayer does not receive the data on its UDP ports..it timesout and then tries RTSP TCP interleaved (RTP/AVP/TCP). This is fine but it introduces delay of 10 secs or so. I want to avoid this delay, and force Android MediaPlayer to always use RTSP TCP interleaved (RTP/AVP/TCP) for all or specific URL's.

I tried suggestion given in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408233/how-to-force-client-to-switch-rtp-transport-from-udp-to-tcp) to send 461 or 400 error response code to SETUP request. But it seems mediaplayer does not care about the response, and sends SETUP command for both tracks, and then just hangs the connection.

How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: Have you ever solved this issue?

Comment: Why not initialize a UDP socket connection yourself, and handle the stream accordingly.  This would avoid Android handling it for you

Comment: I have same problem, have you solved ?

Comment: Not an expert on this, but ExoPlayer (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html) could be an alternative if your api level is 16 or higher?

Comment: ExoPlayer unfortunately does not support RTSP: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/55

Answer (score 1):

I'm using VLC instead of the native one.
Read the Living555 source code pls.
You can specify the Transport: RAW/RAW/UDP field in the SETUP request to choose what protocal to use.

Answer (score 0):

i might be wrong but AFAIK android mediaplayer does not support RTP over TCP.

Comment: It doesn't as of yet; similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20676092/does-android-4-x-support-streaming-rtsp-over-tcp